# Angular 2 not showing element value in view but does show in inspect element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, model-view-controller

I'm currently developing a small website. On this website I want the navigation bar and a table with cells to show values depending on the language the browser is in. This works fine, but here's the part I don't get.

When I first load the page the element values don't show up.

Example: 
https://gyazo.com/99b376a86b1667aa4db78587e3f92eed

The only parts that work here are the th's. And yes they also translate properly on an english browser. After reloading the page, all the information shows like it should.

While the view is seen as empty, the inspect element is not.

The same goes for all the table cells. All this data is there in the inspector but not in the view. After I refresh the page (doesn't require hard refresh) it shows all the data properly.

In my code all I do is get the navigator.language, put it in a variable and put it in an if statement. if dutch fetch the dutch data, else english. Other than that I simply change the value of the variable in order to show the correct translation.

My jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3zx0temL/

```
    import {
  Component,
  OnInit
}
from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'pekingMenu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['pekingMenu.component.css']
})

export class MenuComponent {
  tableNameNoodlesAndRice: string;

  thName: string;
  thDescription: string;
  thPrice: string;

  seafood: string;
  black_ox: string;
  spicy_chicken: string;
  singapore_curry: string;
  crispy_pork: string;
  veggie: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    var userLang = navigator.language;
    // console.log(userLang);

    // Add Chinese
    if (userLang == 'nl') {
      this.getDutchInformation();
    } else {
      this.getEnglishInformation();
    }

  }

getEnglishInformation() {
    this.tableNameNoodlesAndRice = 'Noodles & Rice';

    this.thName = 'Name';
    this.thDescription = 'Description';
    this.thPrice = 'Price';

    this.seafood = 'Seafood';
    this.black_ox = 'Black Ox';
    this.spicy_chicken = 'Spicy Chicken';
    this.singapore_curry = 'Singapore Curry';
    this.crispy_pork = 'Crispy Pork';
    this.veggie = 'Vegetarian';
  }

  getDutchInformation() {
    this.tableNameNoodlesAndRice = 'Noodles & Rijst';

    this.thName = 'Naam';
    this.thDescription = 'Beschrijving';
    this.thPrice = 'Prijs';

    this.seafood = 'Zeevruchten';
    this.black_ox = 'Beef Met Zwarte Peper';
    this.spicy_chicken = 'Pittige Kipfilet';
    this.singapore_curry = 'Singapore Kerrie';
    this.crispy_pork = 'Krokante Buikspek';
    this.veggie = 'Vegetarisch';
  }
}
```

and my html

```
<table>
  <h3>{{ tableNameNoodlesAndRice }}</h3>

  <tr>
    <th>{{ thName }}</th>
    <th>{{ thDescription }}</th>
    <th>{{ thPrice }}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ seafood }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>&euro; 7,95</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ black_ox }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>&euro; 7,95</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ spicy_chicken }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>&euro; 7,50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ singapore_curry }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>&euro; 7,50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ crispy_pork }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>&euro; 7,50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ veggie }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>&euro; 7,50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How do you do to *reload* the page without doing a hard refresh?

Comment: Also, your jsFiddle looks like this: http://imgur.com/a/w2zj2. Is this what you see, too?

Comment: Angular uses binding. So on the site it actually shows the result instead of "{{ variable }}.

Comment: I just learned that on safari browser it works fine. So I tried disabling all my extensions but the problem persists (Chrome). Edge has some CSS issues with not all borders showing but the data shows up consistently aswell. Firefox is the same as Safari, as in that that works fine.

Comment: Haha, I'm not asking what the `{{ ... }}` are... I'm asking why it is that I can still see them. They should disappear if your page compiles properly. FYI, I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Not sure, I can guarantee in any case that they don't appear on my actual site.

Comment: @Vorzious just for the sake of it... try and set an `*ngIf` for something that doesn't appear in your table, e.g `<table *ngIf="seafood">` just for testing purposes :)

Comment: Almost positive you're not running an Angular app properly.